# Variable return null when using getExtra in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-intent

This is my code to get the variable from firebase, it still return right when i log it

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new TaskViewHolder.ItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskDetail.class);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("Users");
        databaseReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("task")
                .orderByChild("id")
                .equalTo(taskList.get(position).getId())
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                            TaskModel task = ds.getValue(TaskModel.class);
                            Log.d("TEST", "value: "+ task.getTask());
                            intent.putExtra("task", task.getTask().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("id", task.getId());
                            intent.putExtra("impo", task.getImpo());
                            intent.putExtra("done", task.getDone());
                            Log.d("TEST", "value: "+ ds.child("task").getValue());

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_detail);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String task = intent.getStringExtra("task");
int id = intent.getIntExtra(("id"),0);
int done = intent.getIntExtra(("done"),0);
int impo = intent.getIntExtra(("impo"),0);

btnSave = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveEdit);
txtTask = findViewById(R.id.txtTask);
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("TEST-ID", "task"+task);
    }
});
```

[image]

putExtra the variable to another activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API or launches a coroutine return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o/70178210#70178210) - the code inside `onDataChange` is an asynchronous callback, it doesn't run in the order written. It runs later when the data is changed, which is *always* going to happen after your call to `startActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Your `context.startActivity(intent)` happens before the `onDataChange` is ever called. Any code that needs the data from the database has to be inside the `onDataChange` method or it will execute at the wrong time.

So:

```
databaseReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .child("task")
    .orderByChild("id")
    .equalTo(taskList.get(position).getId())
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                TaskModel task = ds.getValue(TaskModel.class);
                Log.d("TEST", "value: "+ task.getTask());
                intent.putExtra("task", task.getTask().toString());
                intent.putExtra("id", task.getId());
                intent.putExtra("impo", task.getImpo());
                intent.putExtra("done", task.getDone());
                Log.d("TEST", "value: "+ ds.child("task").getValue());

            }

            context.startActivity(intent); //  move this here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException(); //  stop ignoring possible errors
        }
    });
```

This is an incredibly common source of confusion for developers who are new to dealing with asynchronous API, so I recommend checking out:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)
- [How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774#47853774)
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)